# Convert Screenshot to PDF in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, frameworks, image-conversion

How might one convert a screenshot, taken on an iPhone for example, into a PDF file. It's easy enough to take the screenshot and put it into a UIImage, but it's the conversion which has me stumped. I took a look at the Quartz framework which is the only one in Xcode that I know to support the PDF format, but couldn't find anything there to make this work. Is there anything native to Xcode that I'm missing? If not, is there a public framework somewhere that could handle a conversion like this?

Comment: Do you want a PDF that's just an image?

Comment: Basically, yes. That's the first step at least. I basically want to design a button that captures the current screen, converts it to a PDF, and then does more stuff from there. It's just the conversion itself that I'm not sure about.

Comment: I think the way to do it would be to create a new Core Graphics context using the functions in CGPDFContext.h, then render the image in that context, and close the context. But I wouldn't know what to do next, and don't really have the time to search more, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It involved saving a screenshot as a UIImage, and then using the very helpful tutorial found [here](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/) to get me going with the PDF conversion. As it turns out, there are functions to handle the making of PDF documents in the Core Graphics class.

Comment: Can you please provide an updated link, as the link you have posted no longer exists?

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't convert a screenshot to a pdf. You would create a screenshot, create a pdf and insert the screenshot image into the first page of the pdf.

Untested code to create image:

```
nameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage.png"];
fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
namePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
namePath = [thumbnailPath nameStr];

CGRect contextRect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);  
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
UIImage *myImage    = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Untested code to add image to a pdf:

```
pageSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 768);
fileName = @"myFile.pdf";
pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

[myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 1024, 768];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

p.s. assuming ipad 1024 x 768 above